# Force.com Project in Eclipse: OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space

Tags: force.com, eclipse, custom, object

I'm trying to load in one custom object using Force.com IDE in Eclipse, but I keep getting this error. Is there any way to increase the memory usage or prevent this error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The organization that you are working on may have several, large managed packages installed. To check if they exist, look under

- Setup
- Installed Packages in Classic and Setup
- Apps
- Installed Packages in LEX. 
  Any packages that display an icon with a blue arrow pointing down is a managed package.

It is standard behavior for the IDE to extract read-only copies of managed packages (**Partners and AppExchange developers take note:** your managed package's code is marked as 'Hidden' in these read-only copies).

The extract can be completed if you increase the memory allowance for Eclipse and continue to wait for a the build to complete.  To expand Eclipse's memory allowance:

- Open the eclipse.ini file in the main Eclipse folder
- Increase the -Xmx property to 1200m (this is 1.2 Gigs of RAM).

**Note:** Additional memory allowance up to 2 GB and beyond may require the 64-bit edition of Eclipse and JVM

If you receive the time-out message, click Continue and eventually the build will complete.  Some users have witnessed wait times of up to 80 minutes.

Reference: [Force.com IDE times out or displays a Java heap size error when new project is built](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000163412&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

Codey's answer is correct and will solve the problem. But I use a hack which works for me always.

When you get the error of Java Heap size, just cancel it. Select option none and then finish. It will get all the components and you don't need to wait much.

[image]